# Fetching timeline posts from linkedin

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch user posts from Linkedin timeline.

As I fetched from Twitter timeline. example: http://jawadahmed.base.pk/myTweets/

I am giving user_id and screen_name to twitter API and it show me my tweets in my website.

Now I want same work in LinkedIn

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to be a member's network updates via the LinkedIn API. You can find out what else you can do and how to do it on the LinkedIn Developer Site: https://developer.linkedin.com/

Comment: Anna Keramaty, do you have any same Idea about facebook ?
I am successfully fetched Facebook Page posts, but I want to fetch user timeline posts as I fetched my Tweets ?